# Fast pass-through Trimming/Cutting of Videos without re-encoding

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm searching for a way to very quickly and efficiently trim and Cut my raw video material without the need to re-encode.

My raw material mostly consists of a big number of clips from my Drone for example. The purpose is to throw away all really trashy parts, e.g. when trying to setup the correct angle / shot or purely flying the Drone around --> Just to save storage, directly while viewing the material after coming home from a shoot.

Doing it in Premiere is quick and easy, has very nice shortcuts, very straight forward, but requires lengthy encoding times while exporting to a new .mp4 file. Maybe I'm missing something and this can be done easily to just pass-through the original videostream in trimmed version? If no, the other option I know of, is the software "LosslessCut". It is great and convenient - but rather for single video files. It's a bit time consuming to open up each and every video file on its own, ending up with strangely named splitfiles etc etc...

Do you know another better way doing so?